# Duplicating extenal items into an array

Tags: actionscript-3

If i was loading external content, such as images or what not will the array load the items twice for example:

```
     load = array(){
       load images( "local/folder/www.example.com/" );
       items("car.jpeg","bike.jpeg","bike.jpeg");
     }
```

The above is in theory, if you notice twice i have the "bike.jpeg" image in the array;
its key value would be either `items[1]` or `items [2]`.

so with the above idea in mind would this bike image be loaded twice or just referenced in the array from the first initial load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the images are going to be cached by Flash. You can check that in Firebug for example where subsequent requests appear as grayed out (pulled from cache). So you can load the same image several times without much hit on your app's performance.

Comment: Well now iv managed to come up with an easy solution to dynamically duplicating swf in flash by putting them into an array then referencing there key within the array.load the same file how many times into it will be duplicated then add child to where ever placed cool